# Ignite server stops respondings with many "Failed to send message to remote node"

Tags: .net, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6. I have one server node and many client ones. After some time server stops responding on the clients' responses. There are many events of this type in the server's log:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=faacfe91-f557-45ef-970f-d193d1940b9a, addrs=[AS-cash1new.ast.loc/192.168.0.88:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3459)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2987)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2870)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2713)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2672)
```

Here is the full log for server: https://yadi.sk/d/gSr8k1zyuxBVWg

This fixes after the server restart.

Comment: I can see some strange things in the log. Is it possible to get logs from the client node with 192.168.0.157 address? It seems to be kicked from the cluster. By the way something happens with baseline.

Comment: Here is the client's log: https://yadi.sk/d/gp5Rv8XBZpD_SQ It is constantly dropping from the cluster for some reason. Can increasing of 'clientFailureDetectionTimeout' help? As for me, it's big - 60 sec

Comment: I can see that the node is being kicked from the cluster because of long JVM pauses, for example `Possible too long JVM pause: 414984 milliseconds.`. Even taking of a thread dump takes about 1 minute. Do you have gc logs? Do you have your nodes deployed on a virtual machine? Maybe something is happening under the hood?

Comment: This computer has a very strange behavior - I've switched it off the cluster. It's not a virtual machine, but it's a very old machine and I cannot inspect what's going wrong. And also I don't have a GC log for it, but now I'll analyze the behavior of the cluster without it.